# How to remove a marker from the previous point from GoogleMap and add another new marker into that position

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am trying to remove a marker from the previous position and add a new marker into that position again in google map. I don't want to clear the whole map.
Please help.

Comment: get marker of map and remove last object

Answer (score 0):

To remove the marker set map property to nil.

```
marker.map = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newMarker = GMSMarker(position: oldMarker.position)
newMarker.map = mapView
oldMarker.map = nil
```